# Add Xelement in existing XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have XML with details. I want to copy the entire `<Details>` node and create updated `<Details>` node with the exact same attribute.

My XML looks like this:

```
<root>        
    <Details>
        <A.EMPLID>0000177008</A.EMPLID>
            <G.LAST_NAME>Huziak-Clark</G.LAST_NAME>
            <G.FIRST_NAME>Tracy</G.FIRST_NAME>      
    </Details>      
</root>
```

I would like to create a new node like this

```
<root>        
    <Details>
            <A.EMPLID>0000177008</A.EMPLID>
            <G.LAST_NAME>Huziak-Clark</G.LAST_NAME>
            <G.FIRST_NAME>Tracy</G.FIRST_NAME>      
    </Details>  
    <Newdetails>
        <Details>
            <A.EMPLID>0000177008</A.EMPLID>
            <G.LAST_NAME>Huziak-Clark</G.LAST_NAME>
            <G.FIRST_NAME>Tracy</G.FIRST_NAME>      
        </Details>  
    </Newdetails>
</root>
```

I have used `XElement` like this, but it is just adding `<NewDeatils/>` node in `XDocument` but not remaining nodes.

```
foreach(XElement e in XDocument.Descendants("Details"))
{
     XDocument.Root.Element.Add("NewDetails",XElement("Deatils");
}
```

How to select the entire `XElement` and append it under `<Newdetails>` node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load the file and get all `Descendants` named "Details".

```
var file = @"XMLFile.xml";
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
var details = doc.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "Details");
```

This gives you a collection of `Details` nodes, in your example file only one.
Then I'd iterate through them, and for each of them create a new `XElemen` named `NewDetails` and add the existing element as a child.

Note here that I'm getting the `details.Count()` before the loop and using it as the limit. If you did a `foreach` instead, this will turn into an infinite loop so be careful.

```
var count = details.Count();
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var newDetails = new XElement("NewDetails");
    newDetails.Add(details);
    doc.Root.Add(newDetails);
}
```

Save it to confirm results.

```
var fileNew = @"XMLFile2.xml";
doc.Save(fileNew);
```

Here's the file before and after adding the node:

### BEFORE:

[image]

### AFTER:

[image]

Comment: what is I declared details as a XElement. I need to add other nodes in newdetails along with details?